# Synchronization of Monero (javascript) wallet too long

Tags: synchronization, wallet, javascript

When I run the **monerojs library** method for wallet synchronization on my local testnet node, it takes too long to synchronize. Every time I run the code it's like it's re-syncing all over again. Reading on other Stack questions for other users who used **monero-wallet-cli**, one needs to use an exit method to not lose sync data.

From the **monerojs** documentation I can't find such a method (https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/MoneroWalletFull.html). I don't know if I'm just configuring the wallet wrong.

This is my code:

```
  let wallet = await monerojs.createWalletFull({
    networkType: MoneroNetworkType.TESTNET,
    password: "<passw>",
    mnemonic: "<Mnemonic>",
    serverUri: "http://127.0.0.1:28081",
    });
    

  const syncResult = await wallet.sync();
  console.log('Sync progress:', syncResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

> From the **monerojs** documentation I can't find such a method...

It's documented, see: https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/MoneroWallet.html#close

Ref:

> (async) close(save)
>
> Optionally save then close the wallet.

Comment: I also found the save() [https://moneroecosystem.org/monero-javascript/MoneroWallet.html#save] method which saves the state of the wallet without necessarily closing it.